# MS Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Import/Export-Database with Default Value or Binding

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to clone a database and its tables and data (which runs a MS SQL Server 2008) to a new one (which runs a MS SQL Server 2012).

I know there is the possibility to do so with

"Tasks->Import Data"

and the transfer worked fine for the tables and the data of the tables. Sadly the old database also has set "Default Value or Binding"-Properties for some columns. These seem to have been lost during the transfer. Is there a way to tranfer these values as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to a create a "create script" for your source table and use that script to create your target structure. Then you can copy the data using the import wizard.